# Visual Studio Community Update 1 error

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

After I update the Visual Studio 2015 Community, when I want to create the UWP Project, all my XAML code is underlined with blue color, and the error shown.

Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Utility.BindingWrapper`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Any way to solve it?
Thank You.

Comment: That Update 1 is marked as RC, so no real value to discuss it here. Once Microsoft ships a final release, I think such issues should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i did not find any solution.But the project can be build and successful.it really make me uncomfortable ..At the same time I cannot debugging my project on my phone because of error DEP6100 and DEP6200. So I have to use Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile..

Comment: I think you need to repair your Visual Studio or need to wait for further update of Visual Studio at the end of this month that mention in event Connect();